# OpenVPN on Ubuntu server 22.04 not connecting client

Tags: server, 22.04, openvpn

Summarize the problem.
I've followed this [guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-22-04-lts-set-up-openvpn-server-in-5-minutes/) to install OVPN on my remote VPS Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
The process described is very simple and I can complete the installation.
The problem is I cannot connect any client to the OVPN server through internet even if it is up and running on my VPS.

Describe what you’ve tried.
I did the installation as the root user. I have downloaded the .ovpn client file to my mac OSX 10.16 (and iOS 15) and loaded to the app OpenVPN Connect v.3.4.3.

Provide details.

```
root@localhost:~# systemctl status openvpn@server
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-01-11 15:30:03 CET; 26min ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
   Main PID: 408660 (openvpn)
     Status: "Initialization Sequence Completed"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 2249)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 52ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@server.service
             └─408660 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/op>

Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: GID set to nogroup
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: UID set to nobody
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: IFCONFIG POOL IPv4: base=10.8.0.2 size=253
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Jan 11 15:30:03 localhost ovpn-server[408660]: Initialization Sequence Completed


root@localhost:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)


root@localhost:~# netstat -anp | grep openvpn
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                           408660/openvpn      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTED     96452780 408660/openvpn       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     96452775 408660/openvpn
```

Comment: What do you find in the logs?